# ZK Proof that a blinded message (for a blind signature) contains a certain value

Tags: rsa, zero-knowledge-proofs, cryptocurrency, blind-signature

I am toying with eCash systems and blind signatures, and I started with Chaum's original formulation. 
In particular, I'm using this formulation from [this link](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~nasghar/co685.pdf):

User `U` chooses blinder `r` and blinds message `m` with

```
m' = r^e H(m) mod n
```

and submits `m'` to the server. He receives a signature `s` for `H(m)`.

Now, my original `m` should have two delimited fields, a serial number `S` and a value `V`, and although `S` should remain unknown to the bank, the bank wants to know for sure that it is encrypting `V` and not some other value. It is important that the user shows `S` at the time of spending the key, but that this cannot be linked back to the request for the blind signature.

For the `V` part, I'm thinking of using a ZK proof, specifically a Sigma-protocol, to prove V is encoded in the hash. To do this, I'm planning to use a Pedersen hash, on a group `G` with known generators `g,h` such that their relative discrete log is not known.

Then,

```
H(m) = H(S, V) = g^S h^V
```

The User would send to the Signer a blinded value

```
m' = r^e H(S,V) mod n
```

where the group element `H(m)` is serialized and interpreted as an integer.

The user would also send a ZK Proof for these statements:

```
Private Inputs: r, S, A
Public Inputs: m', e, V, g, h, n

Statement:
m' = r^e * A
A  = serialized version of g^S h^V
```

The signer does not really care about the format of `S`, as long as there is something in there. What it wants to be certain of is that the value it is signing, `V`, is what has been publicly revealed (so that it can deduct the owner's account by the correct balance).

If the proof is correct, the Signer signs the message `m'` and the User unblinds it to become `s = H(m)^d`.

When the user spends the note, he will present the values `(S, V, s)`. A merchant can verify the signature by checking

```
VerifySig(s, H(S, V)) == True
```

and checking if that `S` has already been seen before (to prevent double-spend).
Importantly, neither `S` nor `H(S,V)` have been revealed previously, so this spending is not linkable to the note creation.

I can see there is a frail point in bringing a group element in a proof of multiplication in an RSA-like group. And I haven't written the details of Sigma-proof yet. But does it look like this is a feasible approach, or would there be easier ways to do this?

I want something secure, of course, but my main concern at the moment is performance and as low interactivity as possible. Therefore, I would not like to use a cut-and-choose model.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a working link, please? Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Done, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Just to add a bit more, I have not had the time yet to read the Survey I link to in the details. It seems partially-blind signatures may solve my problem, but there may be better options out there I'm not familiar with.